# Prevent keyboard input from reaching windows

Tags: c++, windows, input

On a windows pc, I have 2 USB keyboards attached.

When a key is pressed on either keyboard it is sent to Windows, And then windows sends notifies applications that a key has been pressed.

What I want is to capture input from one of these two keyboards BEFORE it is sent to other applications, and stop it, do whatever I want with it. The other keyboard has to work normally.

I managed to differentiate keyboard inputs after they are sent to applications via Raw Input, but how do I do this before they are sent to the applications?

What I want to do is have two keyboard, one keyboard that functions normally, and another keyboard that is exclusively used for hotkeys/custom macros.

Is this even possible in Windows? And if yes, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure about differentiating, but a hook will provide you with the means to preprocess the keystrokes.

Comment: Use `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook type.

Comment: Have you tried registering the second keyboard for raw input with the `RIDEV_NOLEGACY` flag set?

Comment: @Jay: A low-level keyboard hook cannot distinguish between different input sources.